# json template reference to an object variable;

Tags: json, terraform, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azapi

I have a JSON template used for a resource in the terraform project.
My problem is that I cannot successfully reference the value from a parameters block in my json template when it is deployed in Azure Portal logic app code view

For my resource (azapi_resource type Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01, I have this body:

```
body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      definition = jsondecode(templatefile("${path.module}/xyz.json",
        {
          .
          .
          uri = "https://****"
          requestBody      = var.params_obj
      }))
      parameters = {
        .
        .
        uri = { value = "https://****" } #it is a string;
        reqBody    = { value = var.params_obj  #it is an object
      }
      state = "Enabled"
    }
  })
```

In my variables.tf I have the var declared:

```
variable "params_obj" {
  type = object({
    pipeline = object({
      calculation_date = string
      name             = string
      abc = optional(object({
          .
          .
        })
    })
  })
}
```

In my sample json xyz.json I have to reference the var.params_obj but is not working and it is putting in Logic App Code View as it is and not the Object values of my variable.

In my json sample xyz.json I tried to reference as below:

```
         "inputs": {
            "subscribe": {
                "body": "${reqBody}" #not working; I tried also with "[parameters('reqBody')]"  #I tried with another forms... not working;
                ,
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "${uri}"   #it works to reference the string uri value;
            "unsubscribe": {}
```

My question is how to reference that reqBody correctly in my json template? because it is a bit strange.

My sample json contains definition and schema for Microsoft.Logic/workflows;

```
 "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#"
```

Comment: can you simplfy this to a minimal reproducable example that we can run to replicate and help fix your issue.

Comment: it is complex because I have logic app which use this json template. note that for my uri which is string, when I deploy my tf code, tf apply succeeds and in the portal I can see the value right; only for the reqBody I cannot because it is an object and it is not referenced correctly I think.

error: Invalid template interpolation value; Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't really provide a clear example that I could use to reproduce I have taken a guess at what you are trying to achieve and simplified the problem.

Assuming you want the request body as a valid json string in the template you need to use the `jsondecode` function to turn the var into a json string before you try to use it in the template

**main.tf**

```
variable "params_obj" {
  type = object({
    pipeline = object({
      calculation_date = string
      name             = string
      abc              = optional(object({
        foo = string
      }))
    })
  })
  default = {
    pipeline = {
      calculation_date = "monday"
      name = "chris"
    }
  }
}

output "this" {
  value = templatefile("mytemp.tftpl", {
    reqBody = jsonencode(var.params_obj)
    uri = "bar"
  })
}
```

**template**

```json
{
    "inputs": {
             "subscribe": {
                 "body": ${reqBody},
                 "method": "POST",
                 "uri": "${uri}"
             },
             "unsubscribe": {}
   }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Outputs:

this = <<EOT
{
    "inputs": {
             "subscribe": {
                 "body": "{"pipeline":{"abc":null,"calculation_date":"monday","name":"chris"}}" ,
                 "method": "POST",
                 "uri": "bar"
             },
             "unsubscribe": {}
   }
}
EOT
```

without using `jsondecode` function and trying to pass the var directly to template I would get the error

```
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on main.tf line 20, in output "this":
│   20:   value = templatefile("mytemp.tftpl", {
│   21:     reqBody = var.params_obj
│   22:     uri = "bar"
│   23:   })
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling templatefile(path, vars)
│     │ var.params_obj is object with 1 attribute "pipeline"
│
│ Call to function "templatefile" failed: mytemp.tftpl:4,29-36: Invalid template interpolation value; Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required..
```

Comment: I have tried to reference in template for body like:
 "body": [${jsonencode(requestBody)], and it puts also the [ ] when it is apply by tf apply.

in the logic app code view I can see:
 "body": "["{"pipeline":{"abc":null,"calculation_date":"monday","name":"chris"}}"]" and the is not fine. I need somehow to make to be without [] and my body will work in logic app.

Comment: I have tried as you recommended. to have:
  reqBody = jsonencode(var.params_obj)

and to reference in json like:
"subscribe": {
                    "body": ${requestBody},  #without double quotes
                    "method": "POST",
                    "uri": "${functionAppUri}"
                },
                "unsubscribe": {}

and it seems is working fine now in azure portal. I am trying now with including "" as you said.

Comment: Not working if I try "body": "${reqBody}"  including "" for ${reqBody} , making error like:
Call to function "jsondecode" failed: invalid character 'p' after object key:value pair.

But great it works without "" and encoding it.

Comment: Why are you trying to wrap it in quotes?

Comment: I was following your suggestion. Thank you, Chris, for your prompt responses!

Comment: Ah sorry  i see. I wasn't encoding the json after template rendering. so actually the quotes shouldn't be present for it to be valid json. I have updated the answer

Comment: I am trying now to use it as well in a powershell script but I cannot be taken correctly:

I am trying like: $logicAppDefinition.triggers.Recurrence.recurrence.schedule.hours = @('$scheduleHour') and it replacing with "hours": [
            "$scheduleHour"
          ], and I need to be without double quotes. 
If I use "hours": [
            null
          ] but it is not null.  It should appear like:
"hours": [
            @${scheduleHour}
          ] .

Comment: I am using a powershell script adapted to my case to generate/download from Azure  Portal the logic app but it takes the logic app with parameters as values and I need to be downloaded same as in JSON template used when I deployed logic apps.

Comment: I need to reference somehow that variable from definition, requestBody which is an object. It cannot be Call to function "jsondecode" failed: invalid character 'p' after object key:value pair in my case below:
 #Next comment

Comment: body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      definition = jsondecode(templatefile(local.file_path,
        {
          scheduleHour     = tostring(var.schedule_hour)
          scheduleMinute   = tostring(var.schedule_minute)
          Uri   = "https://..."
          #requestBody      = var.func_app_parameters
      }))
      state = "Enabled"
    }
  })