# powershell script -replace a json array (escape $var to be treated as a text without double quote)

Tags: json, powershell, azure-logic-apps

I have solve this topic ([json template reference to an object variable;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78049924/json-template-reference-to-an-object-variable/78050029?noredirect=1#comment137598169_78050029)) and my problem is now a bit related to previous topic because I need somehow to use same template json used in the generator powershell script below:

```
function DownloadLogicAppJson([string] $resourceGroup, [string] $logicAppName, [string] $fileName) {

Write-Host "Downloading Logic App: $logicAppName"
Write-Host 'Resource Group:' $resourceGroup
Write-Host 'Output File: ' $fileName

$logicApp = Get-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $logicAppName
$logicAppText = $logicApp.Definition.ToString()
$logicAppDefinition = $logicApp.Definition

$logicAppText = $logicAppText -replace '"timeZone": ".*?"', '"timeZone": "${scheduleTimezone}"'       #timezone is a String variable;
$logicAppText = $logicAppText -replace '"body": .*?,', '"body": ${requestBody},'  #requestBody is an Object variable;

#$logicAppText = $logicAppText -replace '"hours": [.*]', '"hours": [$scheduleHour]' #a string variable;
$logicAppDefinition = $logicAppText | ConvertFrom-Json

$logicAppText = $logicAppDefinition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
$logicAppText | Out-File -FilePath .\$fileName  

Write-Host "Logic App definition JSON downloaded and saved to: $fileName"
```

}

DownloadLogicAppJson -resourceGroup $resourceGroup -logicAppName $logicAppName -fileName $outputFileName

My problem is on that variable scheduleHours and requestBody because they cannot be treated as I deployed my initial json when I deployed logic app:
Initially (solution agreed):

> "recurrence": {
> "frequency": "Day",
> "interval": 1,
> "schedule": {
> **"hours": [
> ${scheduleHour}       #WITHOUT DOUBLEQUOTES; here is a number var;
> ],
> "minutes": [
> ${scheduleMinute}     #WITHOUT DOUBLEQUOTES; here is a number var;
> ]**
> },
> "timeZone":  "${scheduleTimezone}"      #here is a string, works;
> },
> "type": "Recurrence"

After I deployed the above code-part, I have in Azure Portal in Logic App code view like:

"recurrence": {
"frequency": "Day",
"interval": 1,
"schedule": {
"hours": [
15
],
"minutes": [
0
]
},
"timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"

Ok, If I run the above powershell script to generate the new JSON template from the portal logic app, it takes as it is with values but I need to be parameterized because I have more than 1 logic app and they have different values because I have there different tfvars used for each environment. I want to be a general template generated parameterized, not with values.

*I know the JSON deployed initially is not a good because it has no "" used for scheduleHours , but it works to be deployed and to reference that values of $scheduleHours .
How can I do in powershell this replacement?

I've tried also with:

> $logicAppText = $logicAppText -replace '"hours": [.*?]', '"hours":
> [${scheduleHour}]' -> generating as  "hours": [15]

I need to generate it as: "hours": ${scheduleHour}

I've tried another approach:

> $logicAppDefinition = $logicApp.Definition
> $logicAppDefinition.triggers.Recurrence.recurrence.schedule.hours = @($scheduleHour)
> -> generates "hours": [ null ];

Tried to escape like: $logicAppText = $logicAppText -replace '**"hours": [.*?]'**, '"hours": [`${scheduleHour}]' but not working, it generates with value 15;

I am not sure also about [.*?] is right one;

I tried with:   $logicAppDefinition.triggers.Recurrence.recurrence.schedule.hours = @('$scheduleHour')
not working as expecting because it generates:"hours": [
"$scheduleHour"
] where I need without double quotes, like $scheduleHour

Comment: ```$logicAppDefinition.triggers.Recurrence.recurrence.schedule.hours = @('$scheduleHour')``` generates ```"hours": [ "$scheduleHour" ]``` because you're *explicitly* specifying an *array* as the value - ```@('$scheduleHour')``` (with single quotes) means "make a new array object and add the literal string '$scheduleHour' to it", which then serialises to json as ```[ "$scheduleHour" ]```. If you want the resulting json to be ```"hours": 15``` just use ```$logicAppDefinition.triggers.Recurrence.recurrence.schedule.hours = $scheduleHour```.

Comment: Even if I use $logicAppDefinition.triggers.Recurrence.recurrence.schedule.hours = $scheduleHour, the generator pwshell scripts works and generate the json template with "hours" : [ 15 ], but I need to be generated exactly like: "hours" : [ $scheduleHours ]  (without double-quotes), this I am looking for a regex replacement to do this somehow

Comment: In is general a bad practice to peek and poke into [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) object strings (as e.g. a `Json` and `XML`) using string methods like `Replace`. What about simply: `$logicAppDefinition.triggers.Recurrence.recurrence.schedule.hours = @([int]$scheduleHour)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried with: `$logicAppDefinition.triggers.Recurrence.recurrence.schedule.hours = @('$scheduleHour')` not working as expecting because it generates: `"hours": [ "$scheduleHour" ]` where I need without double quotes, like `$scheduleHour`

I'd go for this approach and then use `-replace` to remove the `"`'s around the variable expressions afterwards:

```
$logicAppDefinition = $logicApp.Definition
$logicAppDefinition.triggers.Recurrence.recurrence.schedule.hours = @('$scheduleHour')

# use regex to replace `"$scheduleHour"` with `$scheduleHour`
$logicAppUpdatedText = ($logicAppDefinition |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100) -replace '"$(\w+)"','$$$1'

$logicAppUpdatedText |Out-File -FilePath .\$fileName
```

Comment: I solved converting the variable tostring() and after that to let in the json with "${scheduleHour}".

Now, I've remained only with another param/variable which is an object and trying get it working.

I updated my question with 2nd part.

Comment: @be9inn3r If you found a solution on your own, please post it as an answer below. If you need answers to a *different* question, [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Comment: I post here because I am trying to use your sample for another variable which is an object, not a string or number as it was for scheduleHours.

But here I think I am forced to use it escaped, as:
 "actions": {
        "Call_function": {
            "inputs": {
                "subscribe": {
                    "body": ${requestBody},      #without ""

But it still remaining as:

  "body": {
            "pipeline": { ...
            }
          }, and I need to be as "body" : ${requestBody} 

$requestBody is the object which starts with pipeline and other blocks;

Comment: @be9inn3r use `-replace '"$([\{\}\w]+)"','$$$1'` if you want to capture `{` and `}` too. Make sure to use `'` to prevent expansion of `${requestBody}`, eg. `$....body = '${requestBody}'`

Comment: like this you mean?
  $logicAppDefinition.actions.Call_function.inputs.subscribe.body = '${requestBody}'
    $logicAppText = ($logicAppDefinition |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100) -replace '"$([\{\}\w]+)"','$$$1'

is generating "body": "${requestBody}" and not "body": ${requestBody} how I need. or I am doing something bad

Comment: @be9inn3r Sorry, forgot to escape the `$`, use `-replace '"\$([\{\}\w]+)"','$$$1'`

Comment: solved with: '"(\$\{requestBody\})"', '$1'